# Why I get only part of the URL from the HttpContext?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I use proxy to get recource from remote server.

Here is proxy class:

```
public class Proxy : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string url = context.Request["url"];
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.UserAgent = context.Request.UserAgent;
        request.ContentType = context.Request.ContentType;
        request.Method = context.Request.HttpMethod;

        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Timeout = 100000;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = 100000;
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = response.ContentType;
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream == null) return;

                responseStream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
                context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my ajax call to remote service:

```
function wfs(layer) {

    let dest_url = "https://www.mysited.com/geodata2055/service/mapagent.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&MAXFEATURES=500&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=ns216630453:WW_MONITOR";
    let proxy_url = "/localhost/Proxy.ashx?url=";
    let url = proxy_url + dest_url;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url); // depricated-'/proxy.ashx?url='+

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log("loader success");
        } else {
            console.log("loader fail");
        }
    },
        xhr.send();
}
```

when wfs function is fired the ProcessRequest function in proxy class is triggered and value of the **url** variable is:

```
https://www.mysited.com/geodata2055/service/mapagent.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS
```

While I expect the value of **url** to be:

```
https://www.mysited.com/geodata2055/service/mapagent.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&MAXFEATURES=500&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=ns216630453:WW_MONITOR
```

It seems that `context.Request["url"]` returns cuted value until first '&'.

Any idea why I get from `context.Request["url"]` only part of the **url**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode your query param, because it doesn't contain characters that are safe for query parameters:

```
let url = "/localhost/Proxy.ashx?url=" + encodeURIComponent(dest_url);
```

To further explain, let's pretend we're a URL parser. Without the encoding, you'll see this string:

```
/localhost/Proxy.ashx?url=https://www.mysited.com/geodata2055/service/mapagent.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&MAXFEATURES=500&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=ns216630453:WW_MONITOR
```

The parser will go through these steps as it visits the characters:

```
URL path:              /localhost/Proxy.ashx 
Query params starting: ?
Param name:            url
Starting param value:  =
(some of these next chars aren't valid, but I'll try my best!)
Param value:        
   https://www.mysited.com/geodata2055/service/mapagent.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS
Starting next param:   &
Param name:            MAXFEATURES
Starting param value:  =
Param value:           500
...etc
```

So because it's encountering the `&` while scanning your string, it thinks parameters like `MAXFEATURES` are query parameters for your proxy request, *not* part of the `url` parameter passed to the proxy request. Therefore, when your proxy code runs, it's seeing only things up to that `&`.

Encoding the URL parameter will give you:

```
/localhost/Proxy.ashx?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysited.com%2Fgeodata2055%2Fservice%2Fmapagent.fcgi%3FSERVICE%3DWFS%26MAXFEATURES%3D500%26VERSION%3D1.0.0%26REQUEST%3DGetFeature%26TYPENAME%3Dns216630453%3AWW_MONITOR
```

With this, the parser now only see a `url` parameter passed to the proxy handler. When the proxy handler now parses the `url` parameter, it will *decode* it, giving you back your original `dest_url`

As a general rule of thumb, never just use string concatenation to build URLs; URLs aren't made up of strings, they're made up of URL-encoded strings.